# iOS UITableView Editing with Accessibility

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, voiceover

I am working on an app that supports Apple's voice over accessibility option.

I have a screen with a tableview that has an editing state for the tableview in which the user can swipe and/or tap the red delete button at the beginning of the table view cell to delete the cell.

All of the functionality works fine with voice over turned off, but when I turn voice over on, the delete button is not in the swipe order, nor can you tap it.

Is there something special I need to do to enable the user to tap/swipe the cell while voice over is enabled?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up figuring this out.

Apparently the way the voice over works with editing commands on table view's is that once the cell is highlighted, you can swipe up and down to go through the custom action commands. Once the command you want is spoken, you can double tap the screen to execute the command.

It's a little confusing since the delete button on the cell is never highlighted, which was what was throwing me off.

Comment: not sure what I'm doing wrong but do you know why the VoiceOver does not say my delete swipe left button? 
I can understand why it doesn't show it but it doesn't recognise it at all.
Thanks